# Отправка данных на AJAX в формате JSON (без jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Как можно такое реализовать чтоб по первому нажатию на кнопку записывалась единица ,а при повторном нажатии ноль и все это выводилось в формате JSON + у каждой кнопки должен быть свой ID  по такому принципу :

```
<button  id="user-work" onclick="Working()"><span id="text-user-work">РАБОТА</span></button>

<script>
    var result1 = 0;
    var Working = function() 
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var n_JSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var ID = n_JSON.ID;
    var result1 = n_JSON.result1;
} 
    if (ID == 1 && result1 == 0) 
{
 document.getElementById('user-work').style.backgroundColor = '#3aff3a';
    result1 = 1;
document.getElementById('bisness-trip').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;    
document.getElementById('holiday').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';    
} 
    else 
{
 document.getElementById('user-work').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result1 = 0;
document.getElementById('bisness-trip').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;
document.getElementById('holiday').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';

    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = result1;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2;

}
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
}
};
    var user = document.getElementById("user-work"); 
  xmlhttp.open("GET","con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?user-work="+user+,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
} 
</script>
```

А ЭТО САМ JSON

```
<?php
if(($_GET['result1']=="0")){

    $click = '{"ID":"1", "result1":"0"}';

if(($_GET['result1']=="1")){

    $click = '{"ID":"1", "result1":"1"}';
}
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var n_JSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Откуда в `xmlhttp` возьмется `responseText`, если запрос только что был создан, никуда еще не посылался и никакого ответа не получал?

---

Строчка

```
var n_JSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

может находиться только в обработчике `onreadystatechange`.

---

На сервере код зависит от значения `$_GET['result1']`. Но в запросе этих данных (значения с ключом `result1`) нет. Добавьте его в url.

---

Что означает этот код?

```
var user = document.getElementById("user-work"); 
xmlhttp.open("GET","con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?user-work="+user+,true);
```

Переменная `user` - это ссылка на элемента дерева страницы - кнопку. Каким образом Вы хотите добавить этот элемент к адресу запроса?

---

Переменную `$click` из php неплохо было бы отослать клиенту в качестве ответа на запрос.

---

В Вашем php коде неправильно поставлены фигурные скобки - один `if` находится внутри другого.

---

Вы пошли по неправильному пути. Начните с простейшего примера. По нажатию кнопки, посылается запрос без никаких данных, в ответ приходит строка `"Success!"`, Ваш код показывает эту строку. Все. И до тех пор пока этот пример не заработает, ничего более сложного не делайте.

Comment: То есть здесь тогда ничего не писать var n_JSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: А где же должно возвращать результат ?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста мой пример подправить ? ПОЖАЛУЙСТА